# Prevent user from clicking radio again and without disabling it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<input type="radio" id="Svar0" name="Svar" value="Yes"> 
<input type="radio" id="Svar1" name="Svar" value="No"> 
<input type="radio" id="Svar2" name="Svar" value="MayBe">
```

User can choose only once.

As per requirement, if the user has selected a radio, he can not select another one. Means that if the user has answered YES (clicked on YES), then he can not change the answer to NO or MayBe.

Workarounds:

1. If I disable the radio after single click then it is not submitted to the server.
2. There is no option for readonly.
3. I tried onchange handler returning false, but it makes the user answer disappearing.

   ```
   <script> 
   $('input[type = "radio"]').change(function () {
       this.checked = false;
   });
   </script>
   ```
4. I am thinking of  weird options like transparent div before radio buttons.

I do not want to prefer hidden fields as I have above 60 questions and I find it difficult to manage them.

Please help me any code in Jquery or Javascript.

If the user selects one answer in radio, then the page should not allow him to select another answer and so the first selected answer should be the one that gets submitted.

Comment: Could you post your code in jsFiddle?

Comment: Why not disabling the other buttons when one gets selected, this way the selected one will get sent when the form is submitted.

Comment: ↑↑↑ for example: http://jsfiddle.net/k39y6frm/2

Comment: try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/0mo5jjLt/

Comment: What if they click the wrong option by accident.....?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Still doesn't make a lot of sense. You may want to consider how users will react from radios working differently here than in every other user interface. For all I know, maybe some people idly click each radio button while deciding in their mind, knowing their choice isn't immediately locked in.

Comment: @Katana314: Point taken. They can cheat it. A one-shot timer seems too abrupt when I tried it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another simple option (disable all, except selection, on selection of any). This allows the selected value to be posted back:

```
$(':radio').change(function(){
    $(':radio').not(this).prop("disabled", true);
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/9n8v4heo/

### Update (delay before disable):

It does not appear to be a good *user experience* to allow radio selection then freeze it immediately, as mistakes do happen.

The following example will allow a 2 second delay after any selection, before making them disabled, so you can keep clicking but after two seconds you cannot select again:

```
var tme;
$(':radio').change(function(){
    var t = this;
    clearTimeout(tme);
    tme = setTimeout(function(){
        $(':radio').not(t).prop("disabled", true);
    }, 2000);
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/9n8v4heo/1/

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$("[type=radio][name=Svar]").change(function () {

    if (!$("[type=radio][name=Svar]").filter("[clicked]").length) {
        $(this).attr("clicked", "true")
    } else {
        $(this).prop("checked", !this.checked);
        $("[type=radio][name=Svar]").filter("[clicked]").prop("checked", true)
    }


});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4008acz0/)**

use `preventDefault()` with click event  as **@JotaBe** said

```
$("[type=radio][name=Svar]").click(function (e) {
    if (!$("[type=radio][name=Svar]").filter("[clicked]").length) {
        $(this).attr("clicked", "true")
    } else {
        e.preventDefault(); 
    }

});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4008acz0/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can attach an event handler that disables the default action for the click to all the radios, and do whatever you need to do instead ofteh default action. Tod so so, attach a handler that simply includes a call to: `event.preventDefault()`, and your own code.

See jquery docs for [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var allowChoose = true;
    $('input').click(function(e) {
        if (allowChoose) {
            allowChoose = false;
        } else {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

As you can see, you can use a flag like 'allowChoose' to allow the default action on the first click, and then change the flag and avoid the default action (checking the radio) on the next calls.

See the [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/jbustos/3m99261s/).

Answer (score 0):

**Quick solution:** You can disable the others radio buttons and the selected value remains enabled.

```js
var $Svars = $('input[name="Svar"]');
$Svars.change(function () { 
     $Svars.not(this).prop("disabled", true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" id="Svar0" name="Svar" value="Yes" /> Yes
<input type="radio" id="Svar1" name="Svar" value="No" /> No
<input type="radio" id="Svar2" name="Svar" value="MayBe" /> Maybe
```

---

**Solution 2:** Another solution will be to add a `class` or a `data` attribute to exclude the others, like below.

```js
var $Svars = $('input[name="Svar"]');
$Svars.change(function () { 
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.val() == $this.data('selected') || $this.data('selected') == undefined) {
        $Svars.data('selected', $this.val());
    } else {
        $Svars.val([$this.data('selected')]);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" id="Svar0" name="Svar" value="Yes" /> Yes
<input type="radio" id="Svar1" name="Svar" value="No" /> No
<input type="radio" id="Svar2" name="Svar" value="MayBe" /> Maybe
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the other buttons when one gets selected, this way the selected one will get sent when the form is submitted.

```
jQuery("input[name=Svar]").change(function() {
    jQuery("input[name=Svar]").prop("disabled", "disabled");
    jQuery(this).prop("disabled",false);
});
```